# how to create edge between new vertex and existing vertex using Java API in Titan Graph database

Tags: java, cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

```
{
    Vertex person1 = titanGraph.addVertex(null);
    person1.setProperty("userId", 1);
    person1.setProperty("username", "abc");


    Vertex person2 = titanGraph.addVertex(null);
    person2.setProperty("userId", 2);
    person2.setProperty("username", "bcd");


    Edge knows = titanGraph.addEdge(null, person1, person2, "Knows");
}
```

I have created two vertex(person1,person2) and edge(“knows”) between them using JavaAPI. After some time, I want to add vertex(person3). How can I create edge(“knows”) between person1 and person3 using JavaAPI?
Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using Titan 1.0.0 and Apache TinkerPop 3.0.1 APIs:

```
 // lookup existing person1 by userId
 GraphTraversalSource g = titanGraph.traversal();
 Vertex person1 = g.V().has("userId", 1).next();

 // create person3
 Vertex person3 = titanGraph.addVertex("Person");
 person3.property("userId", 3);
 person3.property("username", "cde");

 // create edge from person1 to person3
 Edge knows = person1.addEdge("Knows", person3);
```

Please refer to the [Javadocs for Titan 1.0.0](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/javadoc/1.0.0/) and [Javadocs for TinkerPop 3.0.1](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/). See also this basic [Titan + TinkerPop Java example](https://github.com/pluradj/titan-tp3-java-example) program for more ideas.

The syntax is different if you are using an older version of Titan, such as 0.5.4, which the code in your question appears to be using. If you are starting a new project, you should be using 1.0.0.

Comment: @Jason..I am trying to retrieve the value using below code :                    TitanGraph graph = TinkerFactory.Open("titan-cassandra-es.properties") GraphTraversalSource g = titanGraph.traversal();                                 Vertex person1 = g.V().has("userId", 1).next(); system.out.println(v.Property("username");    But I am getting fastNoSuchElementException..Can you plz help me on this?

Comment: That error means that there is no vertex that has `userId=1`. The code I listed assumes that `vertex1` with property `userId = 1` was already created. If you need to create `vertex1`, do the same code as `person3` rather than looking it up.

Comment: In gremlin console(I already have property:username)  v.Property("username") returns correct value..but when I try the same using java api..it is not working..

Comment: Did you commit the transaction in the gremlin console with `graph.tx().commit()`? Are you connecting to the same backend configuration using the same titan.properties file? Please update your question with relevant information rather than adding more questions in the comments or start a new question all together.

Comment: Thank You so much..After graph.tx().commit()..It is working now:)